# On the consistency of first-order theories with an infinite sequence of proper axioms

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $T$ be a first-order theory whose proper axioms are an infinite sequence $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...$ of closed wffs such that $\vdash \alpha_n\to\alpha_m$ iff $n\geq m$. Prove that $T$ is consistent.

So I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to first-order theories, and I've only been introduced briefly to the same. I understand that if $T$ is consistent, then $T$ is negation consistent and absolutely consistent. I'm trying to cook up a proof by contradiction, taking the help of one of these two definitions of consistency.

Let's suppose that $T$ is not consistent, in particular, it is not negation consistent. So there exists a wff $\beta$ such that $T\vdash\beta$ and $T\vdash\lnot\beta$. Here, $T$ refers to the set of proper axioms of the first-order theory $T$, combined with the first-order axioms (seven in number as in *Angelo Margaris* including Ax-Gen).

What do I do next? I am trying to show that such a $\beta$ cannot exist, while miserably failing at it. How do I find the contradiction? How do I go ahead from here? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $T$ is inconsistent, then there is a finite subset that is inconsistent, which are amongst $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ for some $n$. But these are all logically implied by $\alpha_n$, so just the single statement $\alpha_n$ is inconsistent. Since it is inconsistent, we can prove anything from it, including $\alpha_{n+1},$ thus we have $\alpha_{n}\vdash \alpha_{n+1}$ and hence $\vdash\alpha_n\to \alpha_{n+1},$ contrary to assumption.

Comment: Is it necessary that the finite subset of $T$ consist of the **first** $n$ $\alpha_i$? Wouldn't it be nicer to talk about $\{\beta_1,...,\beta_n\} \subset \{\alpha_1,\alpha_2...\} = A$, where $\beta_i$'s are sorted according to the indices of set $A$? Then we can go on to say $\beta_n = \alpha_m$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$, and your argument will follow from there (i.e. using $\alpha_{m+1}$). What do you think?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine That works. It’s not any different from what I said, since I just said they were *amongst* some finite initial segment. And even if I didn’t, it wouldn’t really matter since any set containing an inconsistent set is inconsistent.